# I ate the carrots(,) and the soup(,) and the mutton

Tags: commas

I have been wondering whether we ought to use commas to separate repetitive conjunctions in English. In German, we don't; in Russian, we usually do. Could you help me figure it out; or, in other words, which are the correct sentences?

P.S. I couldn't find an answer anywhere, even though I did try hard.

1.1. My cat slept in the tree house, and in the manor, and in the villa, and in the woods.

1.2.  My cat slept in the tree house and in the manor and in the villa and in the woods.

2.1. I ate the carrots, and the soup, and the mutton.

2.2. I ate the carrots and the soup and the mutton.

3.1. I was neither bored, nor jaded, nor exhausted, nor exasperated, nor peeved.

3.2. was neither bored nor jaded nor exhausted nor exasperated nor peeved.

4.1. You can eat the lamb, or the poultry, or the mackerel.

4.2. You can eat the lamb or the poultry or the mackerel.

Comment: I think most people would not repeat _and_ or _or_.  "I ate the carrots, the soup and the mutton." Whether or not you need a comma after _soup_ is debatable - look up _Oxford comma_.

Comment: The usage is "<expression1>, <expresion2> and <expression3>" with mutualization of the preposition (e.g."in") what gives " My cat slept in the tree house, the manor, the villa and the woods. *In 2.1 and 2.2, remove the "the" (I ate carrots, soup and mutton)*.

Comment: But if I do have a few prepositions, do I separate them with a comma? Example: *I have and a cat(,) and a dog.*

Comment: My sense is that there's no firm rule, and you'd want to consider whether it's ambiguous, and whether you've already used a lot of other commas (overusing commas can be tiresome or confusing.) Also consider why you're repeating "or" - if you're indicating uncertainty or trying to be repetitive to give a dignified rhetorical effect.

Comment: Commas in a sequence of nouns or noun phrases connected by  **and**  would  be an idiosyncratic punctuation.  *They fought like cats, and dogs* would suggest not that they were fighting as cats and dogs fight the other species, but that they fought like cats and  like dogs, whatever that might mean.  But commas can be used to indicate a pause, especially in any form of artistic prose. There are no hard rules there.

Comment: 'The time has come,' the Walrus said,
      'To talk of many things:
Of shoes — and ships — and sealing-wax —
      Of cabbages — and kings —'

Comment: The non-deleted form is rare and probably confined to literature. "Tomorrow, and tomorrow, and tomorrow" is standard, reflecting the usual pauses in speech. But I've seen the commaless version, perhaps in an attempt to correct petty pace. Essentially, put commas where pauses seem desirable in cases like this. I'd perversely go with 1.1 but 2.2 if made to pick.

Comment: Certainly no comma when there are only two in the list - _I have a cat and a dog_.

Comment: Variants I've found on Tim's example from Carroll's poem include << ... of shoes, and ships, and sealing-wax, of cabbages, and kings  >>,  << ... of shoes, and ships and sealing wax, of cabbages and Kings >>, << ... [o]f shoes and ships and sealing-wax, [o]f cabbages and kings >> and << ... [o]f shoes and ships, and sealing wax; of cabbages and kings >>. I'd probably use a single comma after 'wax', unless I wanted thoughtful pauses (do they help in this case?)

Comment: My cat slept in the tree house, the manor, the villa and the woods. in the = just once

Comment: I tried mutton once and I'd skip it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your examples—all correct—display the rhetorical device of *polysyndeton*:

> a stylistic device in which several coordinating conjunctions are used
> in succession in order to achieve an artistic effect
>  <sub>Source:
> [Literary Devices](https://literarydevices.net/polysyndeton/)</sub>

Polysyndeton is used to create rhythm, and commas are invited to or excluded from the composition depending on the desired effect—say, an exhaustive tumble vs. a deliberate pile up.

Here are some examples of polysyndeton, with and without commas:

> It was four o’clock in the afternoon and the kitchen was square and
> gray and quiet.
>  <sub>—Carson McCullers, *The Member of the
> Wedding*</sub>

> Neither snow nor rain nor heat nor gloom of night stays these
> couriers.
>  <sub>—U.S. Postal Service unofficial motto</sub>

> There were frowzy fields, and cow-houses, and dunghills, and
> dustheaps, and ditches, and gardens, and summer-houses, and
> carpet-beating grounds, at the very door of the Railway.
> <sub>—Charles Dickens, *Dombey and Son*</sub>

> If there be cords, or knives 
> Poison, or fire, or suffocating
> streams, 
> I’ll not endure it
>  <sub>—Shakespeare, *Othello*</sub>

You’ll need context and your ear to decide whether or not you want commas. Can you sense a difference here?

> *My cat slept in the tree house, and in the manor, and in the villa, and in the woods. And he would sleep in my bed if I let him.*
>
> *My cat slept in the tree house and in the manor and in the villa and in the woods. And he was still tired in the morning.*

Comment: Not entirely. I think it's correct to consider those commas optional.